# Nuxtjs, how to add data attribute to body tag

Tags: nuxt.js

I need to add some data attributes for body tag. How can i do that?

```html
<body data-spy="scroll" data-target=".navbar-nav" data-offset="110">
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can achieve that by putting your attributes in the `head` object of your component declaration :

```
<script>
export default {
  head: {
     bodyAttrs: {
       'data-spy': 'scroll',
       'data-target': '.navbar-nav',
       'data-offset': '110'
     }
  }
  // ...
}
</script>
```

Comment: it didn't work. this character(-) is incorrect. But it works like this. Thank you.
bodyAttrs: {
      'data-spy' : 'scroll',
      'data-target':'.navbar-nav',
      'data-offset':'110'
    }